# save html file to memorystream using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Long story short, I need to be able to save .msg files to .pdf using vbscript. As I can't do this directly using Outlook, I need an intermediate step of saving the .msg to .html (using Outlook) and then save the .html to .pdf (using Word). Is there a way to save the html file into memory somehow instead of actually having to create the .html file only to delete it later (as it's only an intermediate step)? I'm looking at memorystream...am I on the right track?

Comment: Doubtful. The clipboard might be an option, though (copy/paste the message content into a Word document).

Comment: If you are doing this from Outlook are you sure you're not using [tag:vba] instead of [tag:vbscript] *(there are subtle differences)*?

Comment: If you are using VBA in Outlook then you likely want to be looking at [`MailItem.SaveAs()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx).